# Moore Penrose Pseudo-Inverse Fast Algorithm in R

Tags: r, svd, matrix-decomposition, matrix-inverse, cholesky-decomposition

I want to apply Moore Penrose Pseudo-Inverse on my matrix, which is a 20,000 * 20,000 symmetric matrix with rank 19,999. I found `ginv()` function from the `MASS` package and `MPInv()` functioon from `gnm` package but they are not as fast as I expected.

Is there any other more efficient algorithmm to do Moore Penrose Pseudo-Inverse in R?

Comment: Have you tried to build R against an optimized BLAS such as MKL? In such situations, performance gain might be substantial.

Comment: @MichaelM Thanks! This is a great idea! But I am not very familiar with BLAS. Do you mind explaining why you think MKL will do a better job than the default R BLAS?

Comment: My experience is: For "normal" applications, it does not bring much. But for very large linear algebra applications, you can expect a 10 fold speed improvement. Not sure however if this will help to get a pseudo inverse of that huge matrix though. Just google a bit, as this forum is about statistics, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem you will run into here is not with the speed of the computation, but the ability of `R` to store matrices of sufficient size for what you want to do.  A numeric $N \times N$ matrix is stored as a vector with an additional set of dimensions.  The numeric vector takes up about $N^2 \times 8 \text{ bytes}$, so a numeric matrix of the size you want is beyond the storage limits in `R`.  This problem gets worse if you want to compute the singular value decomposition of the matrix, because you then have several matrices of this size.

In any case, setting this problem aside, the base package of `R` has a function `svd` to compute the singular value decomposition of a matrix.  It should be possible to use this function to compute the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of a fairly large matrix.  Below I create a function to do this and test it on an $N \times N$ random matrix where I have set $N=5000$.  The computation time on my laptop computer is $$, although it may be faster or slower on other machines.

```
#Create function for computing Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse via SVD
MPI <- function(matrix) {
  SVD <- svd(matrix);
  DDD <- rep(0, length(SVD$d));
  for (i in 1:length(DDD)) { DDD[i] <- ifelse(SVD$d[i] == 0, 0, 1/SVD$d[i]);  }
  SVD$v %*% diag(DDD) %*% t(SVD$u); }

#Compute the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse for an N x N random matrix
set.seed(75134903);
N   <- 5000;
MAT <- matrix(rnorm(N^2), nrow = N, ncol = N);
TT1 <- Sys.time()
INV <- MPI(MAT);
TT2 <- Sys.time()

#Check the result and computation time
identical(zapsmall(MAT %*% INV), diag(N));
[1] TRUE

#Check the computation time
TT2-TT1;
```

Note that the computation involves some rounding error, so you will have to ensure that it is sufficiently accurate for your purposes.  In the above simulation the computation is sufficiently accurate that the product of the matrix and the computed Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse is close enough to the identity matrix that the `zapsmall` function makes them identical.

If you can find a way to compute and store the relevant matrices within the memory then it should be possible to obtain the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of the matrix you are dealing with.  In my view, the main challenge will be dealing with memory issues rather than computation speed.

Comment: I have no problem storing 20K X 20K matrices in `R`: they occupy, as you note, only a little over 3 GB of RAM.  Although 64-bit `R` has OS-dependent limits on RAM usage, they are relatively large (8 Tb in Windows, 128 Tb in Linux).  For instance, `object.size(matrix(0, 70000, 70000)) / 1e9` returns `39.2` (giga)bytes on my system.  See the help for `memory.size {utils}`.